# Will current encryption always remain secure? Is there mathematical proof?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

Current encryption algorithms, such as AES, RSA, elliptic curve, etc. work based on known mathematical problems. I am specifically interested in the RSA.

Will such security always remain secure?

One way of breaking them would be due to a revolutionary increase computing speeds, making brute-force a viable option. This could be due to invention of quantum computers, neural-network-based hardware, etc. Such technology is at a very early phase, and will take some years to develop.

The other means is to find loopholes in the algorithm itself, using mathematics. **Has it been mathematically proved that these algorithms can not be cracked, or is it a possibility? If so, how likely is it that cracking the RSA via a mathematical weakness will be possible in the near future?**

This should be an important question, since being able to crack such a system potentially could let you blackmail companies, and even governments, since it is their data which is at risk.

Note: I first asked this question on Security SE, a user there told me to post it here.

Answer (score 2):

"Will such security always remain secure?"

No. $\:$ In particular, quantum computers will break RSA and elliptic curves.

**Has it been mathematically proved that these algorithms can not be cracked, or is it a possibility?**

It is a possibility, since [a very-practical algorithm for the Boolean satisfiability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)
would be enough to break essentially all complexity-based cryptography.

(There might still be a secure complexity-based [proof-of-work system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system),

although it would need a super-constant number of rounds of interaction.)

**If so, how likely is it that cracking the RSA via a


mathematical weakness will be possible in the near future?**

Does [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) constitute "a mathematical weakness" in RSA?